# Cost Of Bandwidth $20.00 per megabyte?

Tags: networking, internet, bandwidth, isp

I have been in talks with local ISPS about getting fiber hooked up.  Several of them have, rather cryptically,  told me that they get charged "$20.00" per "MegaByte".

This makes no sense to me.  A gigabyte of data would cost a fortune.  I was hesitant to push the issue because I didn't want to take up their time on the phone, plus I felt like I missing something since more than one of them told me this.

Does anyone know what this might translate into for the end user.  The connections are uncapped and I can download/upload as much as I want.

I must be misunderstanding something.  Total cost for me is $90.00 a month for a 20 megabit connection....

Comment: I happen to be charged exactly $20/megabyte per second (30Mbps at $75/month). What country are you in? That sounds too expensive. Actually, I own my own modem and don't lease extra features like "WiFi modems". I guess if I did, it would be around $90 as well.

Comment: I'm in a rural area of Washington State USA: Okanogan county.  Really fortunate to have fast fiber lines, local utility company got a grant to put it in, since its relatively new I think they are trying to pay for it with slightly higher than normal prices.  Still worth it though since I work remotely from our offices in Seattle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is MOST CERTAINLY no way that their service costs 20 Dollars per megabyte downloaded. This would mean that to download an average sized HD movie one would have to spend **60,000** dollars for that alone- which is simply outrageous.

Likely what they are speaking of is the speed cap of the internet- if it costs "20.00 dollars per megabyte" this means that they charge 20 dollars if you have a 1 MB/S Download speed. Considering that 1 Megabyte is 8 MegaBits, if you are paying for 20 MegaBits per second, then you are getting a 2.5 MegaByte per second connection speed.

If you pay for 2.5 MegaBytes per second they should *logically* charge you around 60 dollars a month for this connection. This would mean that you are technically paying about 60 dollars for a 20 megabit per second connection- Which is generally reasonable by today's standards.

Add in their service charge which I assume is about 30 dollars a month on top of your 60 for speed... and you have *90 dollars a month.*

There you go.

I Would like to note, though, that ISPs tend to round the numbers a bit when it comes to internet speed- what they advertise as a 20 MegaBit per second connection is likely actually a 24 MegaBit per second connection, which is 3 MegaBytes per second.

Comment: This makes sense.  Thanks a bunch for the responce

Comment: Aye, No probs mate!